# How to compare two Series of Datetime by ignoring the datetime format

Tags: pandas

I want to compare two Series containing datetimes. One Series has ISO datetime format

```
[left]:  [2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z]
```

The other one is not

```
[right]: [2010-01-01 00:00:00]
```

I am using the pandas assert `pd.testing.assert_series_equal(left, right)`
Are there any easy ways to do it without explicitly converting them to the same format?

Answer (score 1):

The format on your `left` series includes a timezone, but the `right` series does not. You could transform both series from a string to a datetime format using [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime):

```
left = pd.Series(["2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"])
right = pd.Series(["2010-01-01 00:00:00"])

left = pd.to_datetime(left, utc=True)
right = pd.to_datetime(right, utc=True)
```

The `utc=True` part is important. From the docs:

> If `True`, the function always returns a timezone-aware UTC-localized Timestamp, Series or DatetimeIndex. To do this, timezone-naive inputs are *localized* as UTC, while timezone-aware inputs are *converted* to UTC.

Now, assuming that your series have the same index, you could directly compare them this way:

```
(left == right).all()  # `.all()` verifies if a series only contains True values
```

Comment: This is working. The followup question is what if we have different types in a Series, do we need to check each value one by one? I think `pd.to_datetime(multiIndexseries, errors='ignore')` could work, but it might cause some unknown trouble.

Comment: A Series by definition should have a single dtype, are you referring to a DataFrame?